# Logrotation for a Nodejs Application

Tags: node.js, logging, npm, logrotate, log-rotation

I am working on a very old Nodejs application which creates a new child process using `forever-monitor`. The logs of this child process are taken care by `forever-monitor` only. This is how the configuration looks like:

```js
var child = new (forever.Monitor)(__dirname + '/../lib/childprocess.js', {
   max: 3,
   silent: true,
   options: [program.port],
   'errFile': __dirname + '/../childprocess_error.log',
   'outFile': __dirname + '/../childprocess_output.log'
}
);
```

Everything is working fine in this setup. The new requirement is to rotate these logs every 12 hours. That is every 12 hours a new file will be created which will have all the content of this file `childprocess_output.log` and should be stored in some other directory. The new log file will obviously have the timestamp appended at the end of the name (eg: childprocess_output_1239484034.log).

And the original file `childprocess_output.log` should be reset, that is all its content should be deleted and it should start logging from fresh.

I am trying to understand which npm library should I used for this purpose. I googled a bit and found a few of the npm libraries which matches my requirement, but the number of downloads for these libraries was really small, so I doubt the reliability of those libraries.

Which library NodeJs developers use for log rotation?

Also, my last resort would be to use the Linux tool `Logrotate` if I couldn't find any appropriate library in Node. I am avoiding using Logroate because I want my application to handle the scenario and not depend on the instance configuration.

Comment: hereafther a  simple example

Answer (score 0):

you can use : 
fs ([the file system library](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/fs.html)) handled with methods like **statSync** and   **renameSync** coupled with try-catches block-codes.

Comment: This should be a comment